# graphviz: Arrow "through" boxes, not "from - to" box

Tags: graphviz, dot

I would like to have arrows go *"through"* a box, not *from box to box*. Is there a way to accomplish this (see below) in graphviz?

[image]

(*Why am I asking:* I have some data flow diagrams where multiple outputs from an entity are going through the same entity to be passed to the last entity, and the graphviz output looks like this:

[image]

eg., I find this not nice and not recognizable.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't exist in graphviz.

How about simply omitting the arrow heads in the edges from A/B to C ?

```
digraph G {
    node[shape=box];
    {A;B} -> C [arrowhead=none];
    C -> D;
    C -> D;
}
```

Edit: unless, you *really* want to do that ...

... then you could use [HTML-like labels](http://graphviz.org/content/node-shapes#html) for the node which should have edges crossing through, define [ports](http://graphviz.org/content/node-shapes#html) within the label to attach edges to (in this case, "ww" and "ee"), and have an edge going to the port without an arrow head, as well as an edge leaving from the port with an arrow head, creating the illusion of a single arrow crossing through the port (which isn't visible as such).

[image: obscure graphviz solution with edges crossing through a node]

```
digraph G {
    node[shape=box];
    C[label=<
    <TABLE BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="0" CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="0">
    <TR>
    <TD port="ww"></TD>
    <TD></TD>
    <TD port="ee"></TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
    <TD></TD>
    <TD CELLPADDING="5">C</TD>
    <TD></TD>
    </TR>
    </TABLE>
    >];
    A -> C:ww:n [arrowhead=none];
    B -> C:ee:n [arrowhead=none];
    C:ww:s -> D;
    C:ee:s -> D;
}
```

In order to have nices arrow curves, I also defined compass points for the edges - *compass points* are n/e/s/w and determine from which side an edge is supposed to enter/leave.

Comment: Impressive! Could you elaborate just a bit on how the second graph works? I assume we define a table, then attach a "headless" arrow to the table and through the table?

Comment: I added some explanation for the second graph. Be aware that these kinds of solutions (hacks...) may not work with larger, complex graphs.